# Take value of each column of Google Sheet row and apply formula to it

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Imagine I have a column `H` in which each row consists of a unique image URL which gets updated occasionally programatically.

Is there a way to apply a formula to each row containing the link? I wanna wrap `=IMAGE("link_to_img.jpg")` around it, but it needs to be dynamic so that the link can be updated dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need a script for that.
Still. Since you tagged it under `google-sheets-formula` you can use a helper column and refer to the cell of the link.

```
=INDEX(IMAGE(H31:H35))
```

*(**Do adjust the formula** according to your ranges)*

[image]

Comment: thank you for your answer. So there is no way to solve this without a helper column? But with a script this would work?

Comment: @supersize There is noway to -using a formula- inject within the same cell any value while the cell is already occupied by your `=IMAGE("link_to_img.jpg")` formula. If this is your goal, then you would need a script.

Comment: @marikamitson appreciate the answer! Will use a helper column in this case.